# How Do I allow users to search for destination cities using Amadeus Hotel API?

Tags: json, api, user-interface, amadeus, search-form

I'm using Amadeus APIs for both Airlines and Hotels. I want to let travelers enter in a search form the cities and airports they either want to go or travel from. I see in the test APIs that Amadeus has its own code names for all cities (if I'm not wrong) in the world. I tried in the test API for Hotels. Code Name for London is LON. I entered the name LONDON and the API said it was a bad request.
So if I have a search form for Hotels using Amadeus Hotel API, how can a user enter the name of a city ,eg Beijing and not PEK (which is the city code for Beijing) and still get search results?
I'm cofused. I need explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, our APIs use [IATA codes](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/) (airport and/or city codes) which is the standard way in the travel industry, this helps to have a standardized way to identify cities and airports all over the world.

It is obviously not the way you want your users to enter it. For this, we have an API: [Airport & City Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search). This API is an auto-complete API, allowing to retrieve the IATA code (and other information) from the name. For example, if you call the API with "LONDON" you will get information about the city and/or the airports of London.

We have different guides (depending of your programming language/framework) on how to implement this API and enable the auto-complete feature (showing the different cities/airports when the user starts typing):

- [Airport & City Search MERN stack](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/airport-autocomplete-app-with-the-mern-stack)
- [Airport & City Search with Django + JQuery](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/django-jquery-ajax-airport-search-autocomplete)
- [Airport autocomplete using jQuery, Ajax and the Amadeus Node SDK](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/airport-autocomplete-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found a documentation for the auto-complete system to work for airports. Do I have to configure it to work for hotel search?

Comment: I have another issue with CORS preventing me from accessing data in /shopping/flight-offers/ api. I have asked for details but I haven't received any response yet. I have followed tutorials everywhere but there's no change. This is the link to the question. I will be happy if you can share some info   :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191717/authenticating-amadeus-test-flight-api-with-javascript-fetch

Comment: As of today, we do not offer auto-complete feature to search for hotels, this is in our backlog but we don't have a delivery date yet. For hotels, you can search by geo-location using the Hotel Search API. Regarding the issue with CORS, our API Management Platform does supports CORS, so it might be linked to the framework you use or your implementation. I will ask our support team to take a look.

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't have a problem with CORS fetching data from Hotel APIs, I only have a problem fetching data from Flight APIs